# Catching promise errors inside another promise's callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

The code below runs as expected. If the charge function is invoked, the function fetches the relevant ticket object from `firestore` and then returns it back to the client.

If the ticket doesn't exist, the function throws a [`HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError) with an error message that will be parsed by the client.

```
exports.charge = functions.https.onCall(data => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('tickets').doc(data.ticketId.toString()).get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      return { ticket: snapshot.data() }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'not-found', // code
        'The ticket wasn\'t found in the database'
      );
    });
  });
```

The problem comes after this. I now need to charge the user using Stripe, which is another asynchronous process that will return a `Promise`. The charge requires the pricing info obtained by the first async method, so this needs to be called after `snapshot` is retrieved.

```
exports.charge = functions.https.onCall(data => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('tickets').doc(data.ticketId.toString()).get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      return stripe.charges.create(charge) // have removed this variable as irrelevant for question
        .then(() => {
          return { success: true };
        })
        .catch(() => {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'aborted', // code
            'The charge failed'
          );
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'not-found', // code
        'The ticket wasn\'t found in the database'
      );
    });
  });
```

My problem is with catching errors in the new `charge` request. It seems that if the charge fails, it successfully calls the first 'aborted' catch, but then it is passed to parent catch, and the error is overridden and the app sees the 'ticket not found' error.

How can I stop this from happening? I need to catch both errors separately and throw a `HttpsError` for each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, such problems are can be handled with adding `status` node and then chaining with a final `then` block. You can try something like following

```
exports.charge = functions.https.onCall(data => {
  return admin.firestore().collection('tickets').doc(data.ticketId.toString()).get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      return stripe.charges.create(charge)
        .then(() => {
          return { success: true };
        })
        .catch(() => {
             return {
                status : 'error', 
                error : new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'aborted', // code
            'The charge failed',
            { message: 'There was a problem trying to charge your card. You have NOT been charged.' }
          )};
        })
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return {
         status : 'error',
         error : new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'not-found', // code
        'The ticket wasn\'t found in the database',
        { message: 'There was a problem finding that ticket in our database. Please contact support if this problem persists. You have NOT been charged.' }
      )};
    }).then((response) => {
         if(response.status === 'error') throw response.error;
         else return response;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't nest a `then` inside another `then` for multiple items of work:

```
work1
.then((work1_results) => {
    return work2.then((work2_results) => {
        // this is bad
    })
})
```

Instead, perform all your work as a chained sequence:

```
work1
.then((work1_results) => {
    return work2
})
.then((work2_results) => {
    // handle the results of work2 here
})
```

You can store intermediate results in higher-scoped variables if you need to accumulate data between your callbacks.

Comment: Thanks, but I can foresee this still having the same problem. If I chain `then` and put a `catch` after each one, will the last catch not end up being called each time overriding any previously thrown errors?

Comment: Why do you need to throw at each stage? Just define your own return object that indicaywjat the next stage should do?

Comment: In any event, nested thens are an antipattern. If you're using eslint, it would complain about that..